# Why do some online services and cloud apps market their security and privacy based on legal jurisdiction?

Tags: intellectual-property, privacy, jurisdiction, politics

I noticed many privacy focused apps make a point of selecting which country their servers and data is stored in. Why is this and is their reasoning valid? For example [this article](https://www.cloudwards.net/icedrive-vs-pcloud/) compares the cloud storage providers IceDrive and pCloud:

> Icedrive offers a single storage location — the UK — while pCloud lets
> you choose between the U.S. and Luxembourg. While there are many
> examples of the U.S. being terrible in this regard, whether it’s PRISM
> or the Patriot Act, the UK isn’t much better since the passage of the
> Investigatory Powers Act in 2016.
>
> However, pCloud’s alternative location, Luxembourg, is far better.
> Being located in the EU means your data is protected by GDPR
> regardless of your nationality, and Luxembourg has solid privacy
> protections in general. That said, Icedrive also complies with GDPR,
> even if they might not be legally obliged to do so in the future.

Also in [this review](https://torrentfreak.com/best-vpn-anonymous-no-logging/) the Trust.Zone VPN Service claims

> If we receive any type of DMCA requests or Copyright Infringement
> Notices – we ignore them. Trust.Zone is under offshore jurisdiction,
> out of 14 Eyes Surveillance Alliance. There is no data retention law
> in Seychelles

Does the legal jurisdiction of the servers or data storage of an online service affect the security or privacy of the service in anyway?

TL;DR does it make sense that an app that has servers in the US and stores my data in the US is less secure than if it stored in a country like Switzerland?

Comment: I only see points re privacy in your quotations, not security. Do you understand the difference? What makes you think that they imply your data is "less secure" in the US?

Comment: Also,are you seeking security from the company voluntarily disclosing information or where they are subject to a court order?

Comment: @Greendrake perhaps not so much security in those quotes. But for example if a country that suddenly seized servers with data on them, that would be a security concern. https://www.theregister.com/2016/07/13/the_exodus_begins_vpn_provider_leaves_russia_after_servers_seized/

Comment: @DaleM I mean, regardless of the jurisdiction a company must comply with a court order (or risk being raided). So I guess the idea that some jurisdictions are safer than other is based on the assumption some jurisdictions are less likely to issue a court order on such a service.

Comment: For example just because it's in a jurisdiction that doesn't require GDPR, the service can still follow the GDPR rules. It's not as if being in the EU somehow makes it safer, if I'm not mistaking?

Comment: @user14343 correct, GDPR does not bind law enforcement acting under colour of law. So the question is: who are you trying to protect data from? Plaintiff in a civil case? Law enforcement in a criminal case? Hackers? The company you gave the data to? The company they gave the data to?

Comment: @DaleM trying to protect the data from anyone who is not authorized by the creator of the data to access it.

Comment: "Plaintiff in a civil case" a judge in a civil court could order the defendant or cloud provider to turn over the data, "Law enforcement in a criminal case?" they could receive a warrant, "Hackers" they are not concerned about the law, "The company you gave the data to?... The company they gave the data to?" isn't this more to do with the specific TOS as opposed to which jurisdiction they are in. My point is, in all these possibilities, how does jurisdiction make a difference?

Comment: @user14343 jurisdiction always makes a difference

Comment: @Greendrake Post-[Snowden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_surveillance_disclosures_(2013%E2%80%93present)), there is a blurring of the boundary between privacy and security. If a government uses covert techniques to extract data from companies, sometimes without their knowledge, is that a privacy issue or a security breach? I would argue that it's similar in methodology and outcome to a conventional hacking scenario. Putting your server beyond the reach of such governments can be seen (and is marketed, particularly for VPN services) as a security feature.

Comment: @JBentley That's still just a privacy issue. There is no sense talking about security if the threat model is the government: you are not supposed to be secure from your government by the definition of it.

Comment: @Greendrake Well, we can agree to disagree, but I'm not sure the semantic difference is too relevant to the OP's question anyway. Whether we call it privacy or security, what OP is really asking is whether the service provider's jurisdiction offers any legal protection against [privacy/security] threats from governments. By "data being less secure in the US" (from your first comment) my understanding is that OP is implying that for a US server the government will be able to take legal measures to acquire his data that may not be possible for offshore servers.

Comment: @DaleM maybe this should be migrated to Security SE